# using 12v battery charging by 20w solar pannel, can i use 12 v directly plug in to my 12v 1A router without its adepter?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, voltage-regulator, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

In my home i have installed solar pannel in 9 years ago. (20W pannel, 12V Solar Battry 35 A, 20Hr).
Where my battry is almost dead but still it is working.we can use its 8w load to max 3hrs. But in day time its work good.

So my question is, i have 12V 1A router, that i want to utilize it during power cut. But when i measure voltage its quite fluctuating from 12.3V to sometime 15V. Is it good idea to connect it directly without its adapter?

And the interesting part is i am posting this, using this method.
I am afraid to blow mg router at this time.

I have no inverter, so i did cut the wire from adapter and connect it directly to router.

Please expert explain what is the better option. Please help me to sove the provlem.

1. Will it blow my router?
2. How do i stabilize its voltage to 12v constantly.
3. Can i use my 1250VA UPS for this solar battery?
4. Can I replace Car battery to solar battery in my existing home solar pannel?

Comment: Draw a diagram of your existing setup. Do you have a solar controller? I think this question has been asked before but can't find it...

Comment: 15V may very well blow a 12V router. Use a buck converter (if the battery remains above 12V) or a buck-boost or SEPIC converter to generate a stable 12V.

Answer (score 0):

Most 12V batteries aren't actually 12V. lead-acid batteries are about 13.8V when near full charge. lithum batteries are even worse.

So it depends how fussy the router is about its supply voltage

I would use a switching regulator module to provide stable 12V.

QSKJ does a nice 20W SEPIC step-up/down module based around an XL6009 for a little over a dollar.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume that a "12 V" solar panel actually puts out 12 V. It may be more in bright sunlight, especially when the battery is fully charged. You should be using a charge controller. That may also be why the battery is failing.